# Debugging QGIS plugins using Eclipse IDE in Ubuntu?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, eclipse

I am using QGIS 2.14.1 in Ubuntu 15.04. I am developing QGIS plugin using Eclipse 3.8 IDE installed. I would like to configure pyqgis and debug the code using eclipse. Is there any documentation for configuring settings for developing plugins using eclipse for Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: I would like to know for eclipse if pycharm community edition doesnot support remote debugging. Edited my question.

Comment: Have look to the programmer guide : http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html#id2

Comment: Well i will have a look.